# Group by last register per date

Tags: mysql, select, filter, group-by, sql-order-by

Good afternoon guys...

I have the following query that returns the following result:

```
SELECT 
    r.rec_num as Column_A
    ,c.amount as Column_B
    ,c.status as Column_C
    ,c.currency_code_to as Column_D
    ,c.due_date as Column_E
    ,c.id_recurrency as Column_F
FROM purchase c
JOIN recurrency r ON c.id_recurrency = r.id
JOIN item_product ip ON c.item_estoque = ip.id
JOIN signature a ON a.id = ip.signature
WHERE a.id = :id
    AND r.plano_signature IS NOT NULL
    AND r.rec_num IN (1,2,3,4)
    AND r.rec_num NOT IN (
        SELECT rn.recurrence
        FROM negotiate n
        JOIN negotiate_recurrence rn ON rn.negotiate = n.id
        JOIN purchase purchase ON purchase.id = n.purchase
        WHERE n.subscription = a.id
            AND rn.recurrence = r.rec_num
            AND purchase.status IN (
                'VALID'
                ,'FILED'
                )
        )
    AND r.rec_num NOT IN (
        SELECT r2.rec_num
        FROM purchase c2
        JOIN recurrency r2 ON c2.id_recurrency = r2.id
        JOIN item_product ip2 ON c2.item_estoque = ip2.id
        WHERE ip2.signature = a.id
            AND c2.status IN ('VALID','FILED')
        )
    AND c.id NOT IN (
        SELECT n1.purchase
        FROM negotiate n1
        WHERE n1.subscription = a.id
        )
    AND c.status = 'DELAYED'
```

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1000 | DELAYED | BRL | 2023-10-04T19:48:17.000Z | 11102501 |
| 2 | 250 | DELAYED | BRL | 2023-10-04T19:54:16.000Z | 11102502 |
| 2 | 250 | DELAYED | BRL | 2023-10-09T23:30:20.000Z | 11102503 |
| 2 | 250 | DELAYED | BRL | 2023-10-14T18:14:20.000Z | 12042504 |
| 3 | 250 | DELAYED | BRL | 2023-11-04T12:51:33.000Z | 13842790 |

I need it to return the last result by date and by recurrence number:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 250 | DELAYED | BRL | 2023-10-14T18:14:20.000Z | 12042504 |
| 3 | 250 | DELAYED | BRL | 2023-11-04T12:51:33.000Z | 13842790 |

I tried putting a MAX on DUE_DATE and grouping by rec_num but the result was as follows:

```
SELECT 
    r.rec_num as Column_A
    ,c.amount as Column_B
    ,c.status as Column_C
    ,c.currency_code_to as Column_D
    ,max(c.due_date) as Column_E
    ,c.id_recurrency as Column_F
FROM purchase c
JOIN recurrency r ON c.id_recurrency = r.id
JOIN item_product ip ON c.item_estoque = ip.id
JOIN signature a ON a.id = ip.signature
WHERE a.id = :id
    AND r.plano_signature IS NOT NULL
    AND r.rec_num IN (1,2,3,4)
    AND r.rec_num NOT IN (
        SELECT rn.recurrence
        FROM negotiate n
        JOIN negotiate_recurrence rn ON rn.negotiate = n.id
        JOIN purchase purchase ON purchase.id = n.purchase
        WHERE n.subscription = a.id
            AND rn.recurrence = r.rec_num
            AND purchase.status IN (
                'VALID'
                ,'FILED'
                )
        )
    AND r.rec_num NOT IN (
        SELECT r2.rec_num
        FROM purchase c2
        JOIN recurrency r2 ON c2.id_recurrency = r2.id
        JOIN item_product ip2 ON c2.item_estoque = ip2.id
        WHERE ip2.signature = a.id
            AND c2.status IN ('VALID','FILED')
        )
    AND c.id NOT IN (
        SELECT n1.purchase
        FROM negotiate n1
        WHERE n1.subscription = a.id
        )
GROUP BY r.rec_num
```

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1000 | DELAYED | BRL | 2023-10-14T18:14:20.000Z | 11102501 |
| 3 | 250 | DELAYED | BRL | 2023-11-04T12:51:33.000Z | 13842790 |

Could someone help me? MySQL version is 5

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution that you can do without changing your current query is to extract each `rec_num` with it's `MAX(c.due_date)` separately as a derived table and `JOIN` it with your current query. For example:

```
SELECT 
    r.rec_num as Column_A
    ,c.amount as Column_B
    ,c.status as Column_C
    ,c.currency_code_to as Column_D
    ,c.due_date as Column_E
    ,c.id_recurrency as Column_F
FROM purchase c
JOIN recurrency r ON c.id_recurrency = r.id
JOIN item_product ip ON c.item_estoque = ip.id
JOIN signature a ON a.id = ip.signature
/*add this*/
JOIN (SELECT rec_num, MAX(due_date) AS dd FROM purchase
        JOIN recurrency ON id_recurrency = id GROUP BY rec_num) dt
  ON r.rec_num = dt.rec_num AND c.due_date = dt.dd
... /*the rest of the query*/
```

And remove `GROUP BY r.rec_num` from the query.

Comment: It's not performing... it's taking too long to run.... :-(

Comment: How long your queries take to return results without the derived table?